# Interview question: three arrays and O(N*N)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Assume we have **three** arrays of length ***N*** which contain arbitrary numbers of type `long`. Then we are given a number ***M*** (of the same type) and our mission is to pick three numbers ***A***, ***B*** and ***C*** one from each array (in other words ***A*** *should* be picked from first array, ***B*** from second one and ***C*** from third) so the sum ***A + B + C = M***.

**Question:** could we pick all three numbers and end up with time complexity of *O(N<sup>2</sup>)*?

---

**Illustration:**

Arrays are:

```
1) 6 5 8 3 9 2
2) 1 9 0 4 6 4
3) 7 8 1 5 4 3
```

And ***M*** we've been given is *19*.
Then our choice would be *8* from first, *4* from second and *7* from third.

Comment: A job offer was "C++ programmer" and that is all in fact.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

This can be done in O(1) space and O(N<sup>2</sup>) time.

First lets solve a simpler problem:
 Given two arrays `A` and `B` pick one element from each so that their sum is equal to given number `K`.

Sort both the arrays which takes O(NlogN).

Take pointers `i` and `j` so that `i` points to the start of the array `A` and `j` points to the end of `B`.

Find the sum `A[i] + B[j]` and compare it with `K`

- if `A[i] + B[j] == K` we have found
  the pair `A[i]` and `B[j]`
- if `A[i] + B[j] < K`, we need to
  increase the sum, so increment `i`.
- if `A[i] + B[j] > K`, we need to
  decrease the sum, so decrement `j`.

This process of finding the pair after sorting takes O(N).

Now lets take the original problem. We've got a third array now call it `C`.

So the algorithm now is :

```
foreach element x in C
  find a pair A[i], B[j] from A and B such that A[i] + B[j] = K - x
end for
```

The outer loop runs `N` times and for each run we do a O(N) operation making the entire algorithm  O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Excellent well reasoned and explained answer. :)

Comment: there are no stable sorting algorithm with O(n*logn) and O(1) memory consumption.

Comment: @Andrey: any in-place sorting algorithm will keep the total algorithm under O(1) space.

Comment: @Andrey even if the sort is O(n^2) we still have a O(n^2) algo

Comment: Although I didn't want to ruin your up-votes (previously at a total of 42, rather Douglas-ian) you get a +1 anyway.

Comment: @André Caron fine, but there are no stable in-place, O(1) space and O(n*logn) algorithm

Comment: @Andrey: And why exactly would you want a *stable* sorting algorithm? It's just numbers, swapping identical numbers around doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Joren sorry i used wrong word, i meant algorithms with Best == Worst. Otherwise saying n*logn is not fair

Comment: Regarding the part where you walk `i` and `j` towards each other: I seem to recall this is correct, but you need to explain why, because some element pairs are not examined during this process: e.g. if you increase `i` twice at the start, then decrease `j` twice, the pair `(initial_i+1, initial_j-1)` is never checked.  One (sufficient but not necessary) way would be to prove that any skipped-over element pairs cannot possibly sum to `K`.

Comment: At first iteration, if `A[i] + B[j] < K` it means that we need to increment one of the number but because `B` is sorted and `j` is at the _last_ element of `B` yielding the maximum number in `B` thus the only possible way to continue is by incrementing `i` to try out the next biggest number. -- if `A[i] + B[j] > K` it means that we need to decrement one of the number but because `A` is sorted and `i` is at the _first_ element of `A` yielding the minimum value possible from `A`, the only possible way to continue is by decrementing `j` to try out the next smallest number. -- cont. w/ induction.

Comment: @chakrit: But that reasoning only works for the first step.  As soon as we have `A[i] + B[j] < K` with j *not* the last element of `B`, we have *two* options: either incrementing `i` as before, or incrementing `j`.  (And similarly for the `A[i] + B[j] > K` case.)

Comment: I'm -1ing until correctness of this part of the algorithm is shown.  (As I said I believe it *is* correct, but I want to see it proven!)

Comment: Can you please elaborate the "simple" part? As above comments, I believe it is correct, too. But, how? Can you prove it?

Comment: @codaddict Can this be done in anyway in O(N), or this is the lower time bound for the problem?

Comment: I don't understand. You are never incrementing `j`, so how come you can decrement `j`?

Comment: What if we have to find all the pairs from two arrays which sums to third array. then after finding first pair, which is to be done, incrementing i or decrementing j. I believe one of them will do

Answer (score 13):

You can reduce it to the similar problem with two arrays, which is kinda famous and has simple O(n) solution (involving iterating from both ends).

1. Sort all arrays.
2. Try each number `A` from the first array once.
3. Find if the last two arrays can give us numbers `B` and `C`, such that `B + C = M - A`.

Steps 2 and 3 multiplied give us O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: No need to sort the first array, otherwise perfect solution.

Comment: @codaddict nice explanation, btw! I've spent 10 minutes searching for any other questions with that problem to link, but no luck.

Comment: @Ben Aaarg, who cares, it's only nlogn :) But you're right, of course: no need to do that in the code.

Answer (score 9):

The other solutions are already better, but here's my O(n^2) time and O(n) memory solution anyway.

Insert all elements of array C into a hashtable. (time complexity O(n), space O(n))
Take all pairs (a,b), a from A and b from B (time complexity O(n^2)).
For each pair, check if M-(a+b) exists in the hastable (complexity O(1) expected per query).

So, the overall time complexity is O(n^2), and a space complexity of O(n) for the hashtable.

Comment: You meant `to check if M-a-b exists in the hashtable`, did not you?

Comment: @Keynslug: Yes. Thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hash the last list. The time taken to do this is O(N) on that particular list but this will be added to the next phase.

The next phase is to create a "matrix" of the first two rows of their sums. Then look up in the hash if their matching number is there. Creating the matrix is O(N*N) whilst looking up in the hash is constant time.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution. Insert all elements from one of the list into a hash table. This will not take O(n) time.

Once that is complete you find all the pairs from the remaining 2 arrays and see if their sum is present in the hash table.

Because hash hookup is constant we get a quadratic time in total.

Using this approach you save the time on sorting.

Another idea is if you know the max size of each element, you can use a variation of bucket sort and do it in nlogn time.

Answer (score 3):

1.Store A[i]*B[j] for all pair (i,j) in another array D, organized in the hash data-structure. The complexity of this step is O(N*N).

```
construct a hash named D
for i = 1 to n
    for j = 1 to n
        insert A[i]*B[j] into D
```

2.For each C[i] in the array C, find if M-C[i] exists in D. The complexity of this step is O(N).

```
for i = 1 to n
    check if M - C[i] is in D
```

Comment: I think you mean A[i]+B[j], not A[i]*B[j]. But very clever!

Answer (score 1):

At the cost of O(N^2) space, but still using O(N^2) time, one could handle *four* arrays, by computing all possible sums from the first two arrays, and all possible residues from the last two, sort the lists (possible in linear time since they are all of type 'long', whose number of bits is independent of N), and then seeing if any sum equals any residue.

Comment: Well, you could just hash the residues (or the sums) in O(N^2) time and space, then look up (in O(N^2) time) all the sums (or residues).

Comment: My point was that one is if one is going to have to perform some operation on an NxN cross-join of array elements, one may as well--at least from an O() perspective, perform two cross-joins.  Your mention of hashes got me thinking, though: what about partitioning based upon lower bits?  If we divide the lists of size n into k=2^b partitions based upon the b lower bits, then for any pair of partitions taken from any two of the lists, on will only have to look in a single partition of the third.

Comment: Yes, I understood the double cross-join, which is why I gave you an upvote, but I wanted to suggest that hashing might be superior to sorting. Off the top of my head I don't see the point of multiple hashes though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting all 3 arrays and using binary search seems a better approach. Once the arrays are sorted, one should definitely go for binary search rather than linear search, which take n rather than log(n).

Hash table is also a viable option.

The combination of hash and sort can bring the time down but at cost of O(N square) space.

Answer (score 1):

I have another `O(N^2)` time complexity, `O(N)` additional space complexity solution.

First, sort the three arrays, this step is `O(N*log(N))`. Then, for each element in `A`, create two arrays `V = Ai + B` and `W = Ai + C` (`Ai` is the current element). `Ai + B` means that each element of this new array `V` is the elemnent in that position in `B` plus `Ai`(the current element in `A`). `W = Ai + C` is similar.

Now, merge `V` and `W`, as in merge sort. Since both are sorted, this is `O(N)`. In this new array with `2*N` elements, search for `M + Ai`(because `Ai` is used twice). This can be done in `O(log n)` with binary search.

Therefore, total complexity is `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the three arrays.Then initialize three indices

1. i pointing to first element of A,
2. j pointing to last element of B and
3. k pointing to first element of C.
   While i,j,k are in the limits of their respective arrays A,B,C
4. If A[i]+B[j]+C[k] == M return
5. If A[i]+B[j]+C[k] < M .Increment i if A[i]<=C[k] otherwise increment k.
6. If A[i]+B[j]+C[k] > M. Decrement j.

Which should run in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for a in A
 for b in B
  hash a*b

for c in C
 if K-c is in hash
   print a b c
```

The idea is to hash all possible pairs in A and B. Next for every element in C see if the residual zum is present in hash.