# Find 3 numbers in 3 sorted arrays with sum equal to some value

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interview question: three arrays and O(N*N)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987264/interview-question-three-arrays-and-onn)

We have 3 sorted arrays A, B and C. 
We have to find 3 numbers from each A, B and C such that a+b+c = x

One way to do that will be to pick element from A and B and use binary search to find corresponding element in C. Complexity == O(n^2 lgn)

Is there any other way to do this with preferably no extra space and complexity O(n^2) ?

I was thinking of keeping a pointer at A ...now our question reduces to finding elements from B and C such that their sum is (x-a) but got little lost in this approach .

Comment: how you've estimated complexity of approach ou've mentioned as `n^2*lgn`?

Comment: Refer this existing question:-

**[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987264/interview-question-three-arrays-and-onn][1]**


[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987264/interview-question-three-arrays-and-onn